# Biological functions of Mystique when morphed

Tags: marvel, x-men

I have always wondered how does Mystique's transformation works.

Please spare me as I don't read many Marvel comics, just those random ones which I can get.

When Mystique transforms to male characters, does she also inherit the bodily functions? In X-Men:DoFP, we saw that she cries when morphed as Trask. Since male and female tear glands function similarly (at least what I assume, never studied Biology), it must not be an issue. But what about other parts that act as outlet for some bodily liquids which differ in functioning due to gender differences? Also does Mystique inherit target's injuries and pain along with it?

If Mystique morphs into a pregnant lady she sees, will she also replicate the baby inside. If Yes, when she transforms back to original form, will she terminate the baby?

Comment: Movie-Mystique, at least, seems to only replicate the appearances of certain things. For example, she replicates Wolverine's claws, but they're not actually made of adamantium.

Comment: @phantom42 any idea what they would be made of? Maybe keratin? Or probably some other compound altogether.

Comment: I think we can all tell what you're really asking, so why don't you just say it: Can Mystique morph into a man, make a sperm donation, and then impregnate herself? That is what you're wondering, right? It isn't just me, right?  
...guys?

Comment: There is also another reference which adds to Mystique's power explanation: [How does Mystique change height?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/56960/2765)