# What happens to parts of Mystique that are cut off?

Tags: marvel, x-men, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-2000

In the original *X-Men* movie, Mystique takes the form of Wolverine, including the appearance of having Adamantium claws. The claws are clearly not actual Adamantium though, as Wolverine is able to slice them off in one quick swipe.

[image: Mystique as Wolverine with her claws sliced in half]

The battle ends with

> Mystique stabbed, injured and being carted out while disguised as an injured guard/officer. No mention is made in the movie about any parts of her being left behind.

What happens to the body mass left behind from having her "claws" cut off, or any other additional growth that may be cut off in in another battle (generally speaking, I don't have other examples off the top of my head)? Are they intact? Do they dissolve into goo? Do they magically disappear?

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate, but strongly related: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/26705/can-mystique-create-objects

Comment: Excellent question - I never really noticed that or thought about it before...

Answer (score 16):

According to her [official Marvel Comics biography page](https://www.marvel.com/characters/mystique), she can only change her volume, but not her mass. Therefore, there would be flesh that was cut off from her body lying on the floor where she was fighting Wolverine.

She wouldn't have to become left handed after this, as she could just shapeshift to keep her fingers, even though that wouldn't necessarily be the part of her that was cut off.

She would lose the mass in her body equivalent to the volume times the density of her body that she moved into those claws. So she would not be as dense as she was before, though in the grand scheme of things I don't think she'd have to worry about becoming incorporeal unless she lost a limb or something, and there's always the possibility of her giving up an inch out of her torso to maintain density for her mass.

Also, checking out the [Marvel Wiki Page](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Raven_Darkholme_(Earth-616)), she is noted to have enhanced regenerative capabilities, so any mass that she did lose, she could regrow in a vein similar to Wolverine's (though not nearly as efficiently). Though, this doesn't go to answer the main section of the question as to what happened to the parts that got cut off, this would explain the follow-up to why she wasn't left-handed later on.

According to the [*Official Handbook of the Marvel Universe (Corrections)*](https://marvel.com/universe/OHOTMU%3AData_Corrections_Women_of_Marvel_2005#Mystique),

> As such, her weight is no more variable than any person; she **gains** and loses it through eating, dieting and exercising.

So the flesh that was cut from her by Wolverine would be "lost weight". She could then eat enough to gain a pound (or whatever), then reconstruct her body back to normal.

Answer (score 1):

Her mass never changes so for structures she wouldn't have (tail, claws, wings, etc.) I believe she would push small amounts of blood through her pores and manipulate it to cover larger surface areas to appear as she wishes.

To answer your question, her body material would revert to its natural state without mental commands. So those claws probably turned into a little puddle of blood.