# Why Mystique can't do what Sentinels are doing?

Tags: x-men, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-days-of-future-past, genetics, marvel

Sentinels are mainly based on Mystique's Gene, therefore they can transform and adapt to any target. Then why Mystique herself can't do these? (she just changes her appearance and voice)

Comment: Because that's not her power. Her power is to change her appearance and voice. Trask studied Mystique and learn about adaptation and manipulation of materials.

Comment: I do not have the source, so just as a comment: The sentinels also have the powers of "Rogue", which got captured, too (in the comics). She can absorb the powers of mutants. This important part is, as fas as I know, not shown in the movies and leads to this confusion.

Comment: ... because BAD writing.

Comment: dup? http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/66804/why-would-mystiques-dna-allow-for-sentinels-that-can-duplicate-mutant-powers?rq=1

Comment: @Geoff: Yes, it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Sentinels are not clones of Mystique. They are not one-to-one copies of her and her powers.

Trask started with Mystiques DNA and *built on that*.